# Code efficiency experts - manipulate list - string compare - append element to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a large list with ex:

```
***orginal list***
<div class="ms-contactcardtext3" id="ProfileViewer_ProfileDetails">
   <div cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ms-my-profileDetails">
    <div>office: <a href="http://vg.no">Oslo</a></div>
    <br><div>User type : <a href="http://vg.no">Ansatt i XXX</a></div>
    <br><div>Company : <a href="http://vg.no">XXX</a></div>
    <br><div>phone: <a href="http://vg.no">+47 444444</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to manipulate and move it into a destination div on the same page

```
***List I want***
<div class="destination">    
 <div class="company">Company : <a href="http://vg.no">XXX</a></div>
 <div class="userType">User type : <a href="http://vg.no">Ansatt i XXX</a></div>
 <div class="phone">phone: <a href="http://vg.no">+47 444444</a></div>
 <div class="office">office: <a href="http://vg.no">Oslo</a></div>
</div>
```

**PS - read this**

1. I can't add class / id on the large list so I have to use string compare
2. List may change from time to time so the order of each element can CHANGE, but I know the order

[Fiddler example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nGWcX/1/)   <--  EXAMPLE CODE

Comment: Is there a reason you can't output the HTML like that on page load?

Comment: @SpYk3HH I know it's hard for you guys to understand what I want with this code. But this is just a "hack" to get the design on a page correct :( 

The output are just like that, and I can't do anything to change it

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding a lot of elements to the DOM, then you may want to look into using:

**[createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)**

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM
>   tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation
>   of element's position and geometry). **Consequently, using document
>   fragments often results in better performance.**
>
> DocumentFragment are supported **in all browsers**, even Internet Explorer
>   6, so there is no reason to not use them.
>
> [Reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Notes_on_HTML_Reflow) is the process by which the geometry of the layout engine's
>   formatting objects are computed.

Since you are adding elements, it would be best to add these elements to the document fragment and later append those elements to the DOM.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the page will repaint/reflow while js is executing, so reducing the number of appendChild calls achieves nothing unless you're generating the child asynchronously. This is not to be confused with reducing the number of dom manipulations i.e. the number of changes to the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after. My attempt at efficiency relies on cloneNode to create new elements and vanilla javascript instead of jQuery. It's also more verbose than it needs to be because I have not adopted a generic loop. The regex might not be the best option. You should really compile any solutions and test them with jsperf. I have a assumed that I can't just re-use the nodes in the source container.

I should note the use of getElementsByClassName which I'd rather avoid, but for simplicity I have favoured it over manual DOM traversing and using getElementById

http://jsfiddle.net/qpZ9K/

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-my-profileDetails')[0],
    d = document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[0],
    c = s.childNodes,
    t = d.hasOwnProperty('textContent') ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    rCompany = /^\s*Company/,
    rType = /^\s*User type/,
    rPhone = /^\s*phone/,
    rOffice = /^\s*office/,
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    newDiv,

    company, type, phone, office, node, text, content, link, child, i, j;

for (i = 0; i < c.length; i += 1) {
    node = c[i],
    text = node[t],
    content = node.childNodes,
    link = null;

    for (j = 0; j < content.length; j += 1) {
        child = content[j];
        if (child.tagName === 'A') {
            link = child;
            break;            
        }
    }

    if(rCompany.test(text)) {
        company = link;
    } else if (rType.test(text)) {
        type = link;        
    } else if (rPhone.test(text)) {
        phone = link;
    } else if (rOffice.test(text)) {
        office = link;
    }
}

newDiv = div.cloneNode(false);
newDiv.className = "company";
newDiv[t] = 'Company : ';
company && newDiv.appendChild(company.cloneNode(true));
d.appendChild(newDiv);

newDiv = div.cloneNode(false);
newDiv.className = "userType";
newDiv[t] = 'User type : ';
type && newDiv.appendChild(type.cloneNode(true));
d.appendChild(newDiv);

newDiv = div.cloneNode(false);
newDiv.className = "phone";
newDiv[t] = 'Phone : ';
phone && newDiv.appendChild(phone.cloneNode(true));
d.appendChild(newDiv);

newDiv = div.cloneNode(false);
newDiv.className = "office";
newDiv[t] = 'office : ';
office && newDiv.appendChild(office.cloneNode(true));
d.appendChild(newDiv);​
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nGWcX/3/) something for you, but frankly don't understand what you really want.

```
var ordered = [];

$('#ProfileViewer_ProfileDetails .ms-my-profileDetails div').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var compare = that.text().split(':')[0];

  if (compare === "office") {
    ordered[3] = that;
  }

  if (compare === "User type ") {
    ordered[1] = that;
  }

  if (compare === "Company ") {
    ordered[0] = that;
  }

  if (compare === "phone") {
    ordered[2] = that;
  }
});
$(".destination").append(ordered);
```